# Canon Pixma 5350 prints pages splitted (first 3/4 page empty) Ubuntu 12.04

Tags: printing, pdf, canon

Firstly; I am new to Linux and Ubuntu, so please bear with me. Now onto the question!

I am using an Canon Pixma 5350 printer on Ubuntu 12.04 and Ubuntu found the drivers and printed the test pages fine.

When I tried to print a (one page) pdf, the page got split in two. on the top of the first printed page is about 6 or 7 cm (which also is the top of the pdf). There isn't really anything wrong with this part, except that the printer spits out the a4 paper and finishes the pdf (everything except the top 6-7 cm) on another paper. When it does this, it starts at the top of the paper again.

So what i have printed, from a singe a4 paper pdf is:

- 6-7 cm of the top of the pdf on a page
- everything except the first 6-7 cm of the pdf on another page (starting at the top again)

I hope anyone can help me with this problem, I am trying to make the switch from Windows 7 to Ubuntu and a whole new (slightly more difficult) world is opening for me!

Thanks in advance!

Michael

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved this by downloading Canon drivers from their own website. The driver provided by Ubuntu caused the problems.

Website: http://www.canon.nl/Support/Consumer_Products/products/Fax__Multifunctionals/InkJet/PIXMA_MG_series/PIXMA_MG5350.aspx?type=download&page=1